# UICollectionView error: cells must be retrieved by calling -: -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my project I have multiple types of `UITableview` cell each containing `UICollectionview`.

Initially I loaded 2 `tableViewcell` in 2 sections of `UITableview`. At first it loads fine without any problem. If I scroll the first section it scrolls nice but when I try to scroll the second section it gives me the following error:

> the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

I have the following code to set up the process:

```
    class Home: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.register(SliderViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: SliderViewCell.identifier)
        self.tableView.register(GridViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: GridViewCell.identifier)
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let viewObj = self.viewObject[indexPath.section]
    if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Slider.rawValue{
    if let sliderCell = cell as? SliderViewCell {
        sliderCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    }
    }
    else if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Grid.rawValue{
    if let gridCell = cell as? GridViewCell {
        gridCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    }
    }


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if self.viewObject.count>0{
    let viewObj = self.viewObject[indexPath.section]
    if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Slider.rawValue{
        let cell:SliderViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SliderViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SliderViewCell
        cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.section
    return cell
}
else if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Grid.rawValue{
        let cell:GridViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GridViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! GridViewCell
        cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.section
        return cell
}
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selected")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.viewObject[section].viewData.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Slider.rawValue{
        if let cell:SliderCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SliderCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SliderCollectionViewCell{

            if viewObj.viewData.count>0{
                if let imageURL = URL(string: viewData.imageLink!){
                    cell.icon.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, completed: nil)
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
    else if viewObj.itemType! == HomeViewItemType.Grid.rawValue{
if let cell:GridCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GridCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? GridCollectionViewCell{

            if viewObj.viewData.count>0{
                if let imageURL = URL(string: viewData.icon!){
                    cell.icon.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, completed: nil)
                }

            }

            return cell
}
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tapped")
}

    }

class SliderViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
static var nib:UINib {
    return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
}
static var identifier:String {
    return String(describing: SliderViewCell.self)
}
var collectionViewCellWidth : CGFloat = 15.0
var collectionViewCellHeight : CGFloat = 150.0
var cellSpaceWidth : CGFloat = 8.0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.configureCollectionViewCell(nibFile: SliderCollectionViewCell.nib, identifier: SliderCollectionViewCell.identifier, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 80, topInset: 0, leftInset: 0, bottomInset: 0, rightInset: 0, cellSpace: cellSpaceWidth, interimSpace: 0.0, scrollInDirection: .horizontal)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
class GridViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
static var nib:UINib {
    return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
}
static var identifier:String {
    return String(describing: GridViewCell.self)
}
var collectionViewCellWidth : CGFloat = 15.0
var collectionViewCellHeight : CGFloat = 150.0
var cellSpaceWidth : CGFloat = 8.0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.configureCollectionViewCell(nibFile: GridCollectionViewCell.nib, identifier: GridCollectionViewCell.identifier, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 80, topInset: 0, leftInset: 0, bottomInset: 0, rightInset: 0, cellSpace: cellSpaceWidth, interimSpace: 0.0, scrollInDirection: .horizontal)
}

func configureCollectionViewCell(nibFile:UINib, identifier:String,width:CGFloat,height:CGFloat, topInset:CGFloat,leftInset:CGFloat,bottomInset:CGFloat,rightInset:CGFloat, cellSpace:CGFloat, interimSpace:CGFloat,scrollInDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirection){

    let nib = nibFile
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    let cellWidth : CGFloat = width//collectionView.frame.size.width
    let cellheight : CGFloat = height//collectionViewCellHeight
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth , height:cellheight)
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = scrollInDirection
    layout.itemSize = cellSize
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = cellSpace
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interimSpace
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
    }

    extension GridViewCell{

func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row:Int){

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
}
```

I think the `GridViewCell` which loads in the 2nd section of UITableview causing the problem.  But I've already added `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method. So I'm clueless what's causing the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your storyboard cell, either you set the identifier or not?

Comment: yes I've checked. It loads first time without any problem. But crashes when I scroll

Comment: Is your TableViewCell contains UICollectionView ??

Comment: yes. there are multiple types of tableview cells, each of them contains UICollectionView

Comment: I let you know that, in these scenario keeping the both tableView and Collectionview in the UIViewController is not a good practice. It messed up your code work. I suggest you to divide your sructure like [this](https://contentpedlar.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/uicollectionview-in-uitableview/). Here tableview binded with the uiviewcontroller, whereas CollectionView delegates and datasource are binded with the TableViewcell. By doing this your code structure is automatically divided in aproper structure thats make you to mainntain  it properly.

Comment: I'll take that. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem may be caused because you are returning UICollectionViewCell() in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

if the two conditions are not met.

If at any point the conditions are not met, you return a cell which is not retrieved by calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: as the exception says.

Try setting a breakpoint to confirm if this is what is actually happening.

Comment: I debugged this by setting breakpoint in the line `return UICollectionViewCell()` It never reaches that line.

Comment: what should I return by default instead of `return UICollectionViewCell()` If I omit this line the compiler is giving error **Missing return in a function expected to return UICollectionViewCell** Although I have already return cells based on the condition. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you aren't debugging correctly the only cell that doesn't have reuse identifier is UICollectionViewCell() ..... try to remove it and instead of two if if else write one if so you always have return cell command running on some cell not the cell object. Try it.

Comment: @MoazKhan That's what did a few minutes ago & solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @John Snow, Thanks for driving me to right direction

Comment: @LinkonSid I also posted an answer maybe an up vote :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways that you can use to handle your cells instead of if else then UICollectionViewCell()

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if let gridCell = cell as? GridCollectionViewCell {
            // TODO: configure cell
        }

return cell
```

Another way is to

```
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
 as? GridCollectionViewCell else {

                //Handle error first so you can return a perfect cell if there is no error
  }
```

**Remove UICollectionViewCell() it's causing the issue because there is no reuse identifier for that cell.**

Answer (score 2):

i resolve this problem by
i missed to return cell in one collection view. i am using multiple collection view and i missed to return cell in
"

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CropName", for: indexPath) as! CropNameCollectionViewCell
            return cell
```

see somewhere you missed to return cell

Comment: Aaaaah one hour to find out I really missed the `return cell` !! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I missed returning my cell.

Answer (score 2):

this happened to me too, with the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        guard let cell = 
collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"selectedUserCell", for: indexPath) as? selectedUserCell  else { return 
UICollectionViewCell() }
    
        return cell
    
    
    }
```

The problem was that I forgot to assign the class selectedUserCell to the cell in storyboard/nib.. so once that was fixed,  the correct cell was being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Select collection view cell and add reuse identifier

[image]

Comment: no. I've added this. It loads first time without any problem. But crashes when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the error come from this line `return UICollectionViewCell()`, could you use `assert` to check error condition ?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // ....

    // I doubt error come from `return UICollectionViewCell()`
    // Could you insert `assert` to check error condition ?
    // assert(false,'Error condition for collectionView cell')
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today. Truly the phrase "return cell" where cell is a UICollectionViewCell causes this issue.

My issue was because I was using guard let to unwrap an optional, and due to the fact that the function returns something, which in this case is a UICollectionViewCell, it expects that I return one. So I returned a UICollectionViewCell to shut out the error. Definitely, it came back to hunt me.

```
guard let model  = titles[indexPath.row].posterPath else {
   print("something went wrong")
   return TitleCollectionViewCell()}
```

So i was able to resolve by using nil coalescing which would not require that I return anything like in guard let method.

```
let model = titles[indexPath.row].posterPath ?? ""
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue.
make sure your **cellForItemAt** method should not return **UICollectionViewCell()** it should return the cell which is dequeued.

Check if you have added conditions which are failing and your default return is getting called and returning **UICollectionViewCell()** then this crash will come.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```